# Passing javascript variable to server side php script

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

What I'm trying to do pass javascript variable through an url of action attribute of a form. It looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var imagefile =document.getElementById("imageBox").value;
</script>`
```

html form:

```
<form action="http://myLocation/uploadServer.php?image="+file method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="startUpload();" >
   Upload New Image: <input name="myfile" type="file" id="imageBox" />
   <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Upload" onclick=""/>
</form>
```

It is redirected to the destination page with nothing in *file*.

Is it even possible what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I believe document.getElementById("imageBox").value will just be the string of the file path, and not the image data.  What exactly are you trying to upload? Just the image? The image and its associated file name?

Comment: Yeah ... right you are.. Actually I'm uploading the image to the server and trying to upload it in the database as well. For doing this, I'm following - 1. Upload the file to server 2. From server, upload it to the database. I hope I'm not going to the wrong direction.

Comment: are you actually putting the image in the database? As in, storing the byte data IN the database? Or are you just adding a reference to the image file (on the disk) to the database? If it's the former, I'm curious as to what the point of this would be. The simpler thing would be to just upload the image and then immediately make an entry in the database (while you have the filename handy from the upload) so that you know it's been added... though perhaps I'm still not understanding what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Possible with jQuery POST
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); // stops form from being submitted via the button as normal

// now we post to the dynamic url   
 $.post('http://myLocation/uploadServer.php?image='+file, function(data) {
       //success
    });
});
```

The serverside stuff you still have to figure out though..

Comment: Isn't it possible without jQuery? Actually I'm not that familiar with jQuery yet..

Comment: Oh yah, sorry I didnt see you didnt tag it with jQuery. It is, but its a lot easier with jQUery. Many many lines of code easier.

Comment: That's fine .. Thanks for your response though!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a proper `form`?

```
<form action="http://myLocation/uploadServer.php"
      method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      onsubmit="startUpload();" >

    Upload New Image: <input name="image" type="file" id="imageBox" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Upload" onclick=""/>

</form>
```

Comment: what is the benefit though? :S